# Can not leave Insert-mode in gvim 8.1 after starting without opening file

Tags: vim

I just installed gvim 8.1 on my Win10-machine and wanted to modify `_vimrc`, and to learn to use vim.

I can switch modes with `a`,`i`, `<C-o>` to enter insert-mode, and `<C-c>` or `<Esc>` to get back to normal mode, but only when I opend a file with gvim.

If I only start gvim, it displays an empty unnamed file in insert mode, and no combination of keys lets me leave the insert mode.

I tried:

- `Ctrl+c`
- `Esc`
- `^c`
- `^C`
- activating/deactivating Capslock
- `Ctrl+[` (German QWERTZ-keyboard, `[` is on `AltGr+8`)

I also deleted `msvim.vim`, because I thought that might help, but it had absolutely no effect.

Any other ideas how to leave insert mode here? Everything is fine if I open a text-file directly...

Comment: How do you know that you are in insert mode? Also, what does Vim tell you when you do `<C-c>` (control + c)? Do you have anything in your `.vimrc` or really the `.gvimrc` right now? Also check `~\.vimfiles\vimrc` since you are on Windows...

Comment: @JakeD:
The bottomline says -INSERT- and keys produce printed characters on screen.
Ctrl+C and Esc seem to have no effect - I am still in INSERT-mode.
Will post .vimrc .gvimrc and .vimfiles when I am back on my machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try typing `<C-o>:verbose set insertmode?<CR>`. If it replies with `insertmode`, you're in *easy mode* ([`:help easy`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#easy)). For that session, you can turn this off via `<C-o>:set noinsertmode<CR>`.

If you're lucky, the `:verbose` also tells you the file where (mistakenly) `:set insertmode` happened. But I rather suspect that the shortcut that starts Vim passes the `-y` command-line argument (but it's only effective if no files are passed). To fix that, you need to check the shortcut (don't use one that says `Vim (Easy mode)` in it, or launches `evim.bat`) or your file associations in the Windows registry.

Comment: Error can not be reproduced, I suspect I launched evim on accident before.

Comment: Yes, that might well be :-) Thank you for accepting my answer, and happy Vimming!

Comment: `-y` is the culprit in my case! Thanks